# Increment the value in a TextBox using the Arrow Inside the Box

Tags: javascript, wdio-jasmine

[image]

In an automation code, I want to fill the text-box with a number greater than 0. setvalue() doesn't work. A user would have to click on the up arrow (see picture) to make the text-box editable. How can I make this happen?

```
 <input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiInputBase-inputMarginDense MuiOutlinedInput-inputMarginDense" id="yieldGoal" name="yieldGoal" placeholder="0.00" type="number" min="0.01" step="0.01" data-test="new-program-form__yield-goal-input" value="0.00">
```

So far I have attempted to set the attributes `step`, `value` with a value large than 0.0. It did not work.

$('#yieldGoal').setAttribute('step', "2.0")

Increment the value in the text-box

Answer (score 1):

Please use `val` to set the value of an input element.

```
$('#yieldGoal').val("2.0");
```

Hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: Did not work. This could be due to `wdio`. It has its own function setValue(). Why is do I see this error in the Chrome browser console?Uncaught TypeError: $(...).val is not a function at <anonymous>:1:55

Comment: I think you are missing JQuery, try to add jQuery library and the run this code.

Comment: Okay. Adding another observation. The UpArrow and DownApprow key inc/dec the value. How about calling browser.keys(UpArrow)?

Answer (score 1):

if this is texbox and you use jQuery try

```
$('#yieldGoal').val("2.0")
```